# DataTable not displaying AJAX JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, datatables

## DataTable not displaying AJAX JSON data

I'm working on a simple project with the help of DataTable to display POST data using AJAX. The data shows but lists all the records without paginating. The JSON data is as per the DataTable requirements and other settings as well in Jquery.

Any help in this will be highly appreciated. The code is given below

#### HTML

```
<table id="dataTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Qualification</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Qualification</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

#### Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTable').DataTable({
            "searching": false,
            info: false,
            "pageLength": 5,
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "scripts/post.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "json",
                "dataSrc": "data",
                "data": {
                    table: 'tbl_qualification'
                },
                "success": function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "pk_int_qualificationID"},
                {"data": "txt_qualificationName"}
            ]
        })
    })
```

#### Server-side (post.php)

```
$table=$_POST['table'];
$result=ConnectSQL::GetQuick($table,array(),array());
$result['recordsTotal']=$result['count'];
unset($result['count']);
$result['data']=$result['rows'];
unset($result['rows']);
print_r(json_encode($result));
return json_encode($result);
```

#### JSON

```
{
    "recordsTotal": 27,
    "data": [{
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "1",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Doctor of Medicine"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "2",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Internship"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "3",
        "txt_qualificationName": "OMSB Speciality"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "4",
        "txt_qualificationName": "OMSB Compelition"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "5",
        "txt_qualificationName": "IELTS"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "6",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "7",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "8",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "9",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "10",
        "txt_qualificationName": "amir"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "11",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Sameer"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "12",
        "txt_qualificationName": "amir1234"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "13",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Sameer5"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "14",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Amir12346"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "15",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Zubair"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "16",
        "txt_qualificationName": "dd"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "17",
        "txt_qualificationName": "dsd1"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "18",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc1"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "19",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Abc123"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "20",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Sameer"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "21",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Sameer"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "22",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc145"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "23",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "24",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc123"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "25",
        "txt_qualificationName": "Sameer123"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "26",
        "txt_qualificationName": "dasda"
    }, {
        "pk_int_qualificationID": "29",
        "txt_qualificationName": "abc14567"
    }]
}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `serverside` to `false` (or remove it), or, add paging and sorting information to your ajax request.

Comment: Perfect! It worked! Just for the info, if paging and sorting are added to AJAX request, Later how to link to the DataTable?

Comment: @AmirHussain read all about it [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding     `"paging" : true`.
Also, you should put quotations around 'info':  `"info" : false`
[Reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging)

Comment: I added as suggested. But no change!